# Fabric Crashlytics - Aggregate data from different projects

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have several customized Apps which have different package name/bundle ID. Crash data will be sent to different apps in Fabric Crashlytics dashboard (I guess they have different package name), even if the crash data are same(same type, same exceptions...). My question is: is that possible or is there a way to get the aggregated crash data from these Apps? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you like to do something like this? You could grab the data and aggregate it afterwards.

Comment: I don't know I am able to do this. Can you show me how to do that afterwards?

Comment: I cannot find a way to get aggregated data and I cannot find a way to export data from the dashboard either....

Comment: I guess the only way to do that is to parse the email notifications? which probably is not worth it...

Comment: @Huigege do you want all the data from the other apps to flow into only one?

Comment: @Mike B yes, it sounds meaningless, but this is what I need. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Just wanted to be sure before I posted a potentially irrelevant answer :) See answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

If you want multiple apps to flow into a single "parent" app on your Fabric dashboard, then here's what you need to do.

First ensure that the parent app has been added to your Fabric dashboard. Then you want to use something like this, depending on the kits of Fabric that you're using:

```
Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder().kits(new Crashlytics(), ...).appIdentifier("parent app identifier").build());
```

One important note is that if you're using Proguard or Dexguard, de-obfuscation will not work correctly on crashes from the child app.  Second, currently this only supported on Android.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I will give it a shot.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much.  Just curious: is that possible to send data to both 'parent' app and also to itself dashboard?

Comment: Not currently. You can either have it flow to the parent app or it as its own app, but not both.

Comment: Hey @Mike Bonnell.
I am adding Fabric Twitter Kit into my project now. Method Fabric.with(Context context, Kit... kits) only takes Kit. However, new Fabric.Builder().kits(new Crashlytics(), ...).appIdentifier("parent app identifier").build() is a Fabric, so I cannot add Twitter Kit. Is there a proper way to add Fabric Twitter?

Comment: Hi Mike, it's an old question, but I just read your answer. That's good for Android, but is there a similar method for iOS ?

Comment: There isn't a method on iOS that accomplish this currently.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Is that feature on the roadmap for the iOS SDK? Would love to see that for our white labeled apps to be able to group crashes.

Comment: It's not on the immediate roadmap for the iOS SDK. Thanks for letting me know you're interested in it!

Comment: @MikeBonnell just wanted to let you know, I would like to see this feature too. we are using different bundle identifiers for staging + production although reporting should be in one single project.

Comment: @MikeBonnell we have 66 branded apps that we need aggregated Crashlytics for the code base. So aggregated view or parent app would be a great solution for this. Are there any plans to support this for iOS anytime soon? Why only Android?

Comment: It remains not on our immediate roadmap to add in. I appreciate knowing you'd like to see us do so.

Comment: @MikeBonnell One more user voting for this on iOS. I think this is a must have for branded apps.

Comment: and what about combining iOS and Android apps into one i.e. to have single access to the metrics?

Comment: Not on our immediate roadmap, but you can head to fabric.io/home to see multiple apps in one place.

Comment: @MikeBonnell what about NDK symbolization? Will it work?

Comment: NDK is treated as coming from the same Android app.