# Fabric Twitter/Fabric Crashlytics- How to add multiple Kits

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

Here is the ticket for how to aggregate data into a single dashboard: [Fabric Crashlytics - Aggregate data from different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032726/fabric-crashlytics-aggregate-data-from-different-projects)

We use Fabric.with(new Fabric.Builder().kits(new Crashlytics(), ...).appIdentifier("parent app identifier").build()) to make data flow into one dashbaord;

My question is how to add another Fabric Twitter Kit. Fabric.with(Context context, Kit... kits) only takes Kit as parameter, but the return type of "new Fabric.Builder().kits(new Crashlytics(), ...).appIdentifier("parent app identifier").build()" is a Fabric. Any helps? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add twitter with your crashlytics kit, you simply have to do this:

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(),new Twitter(authConfig));
```

Don't forget to add twitter into your gradle file

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
}
```

The method `Fabric.with()` offers two choice to initiate the Fabric. The first is the one on the top. The context + the kits you want to use (a parameter with ... like Kit...kits means you can put kits separated by a coma (,))

The second way is to first create the Fabric.Builder like

```
Fabric.Builder builder = new Fabric.Builder(this).kits(new Crashlytics(), new Twitter(authConfig));
```

and then put this builder like this:

```
Fabric.with(builder.build);
```

Comment: Thank you @xiaomi ! It works for me. The second way is the one I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. Just think to validate answer if the answer resolve your question. It helps a lot when other people are looking for a similar question.