# Firebase Crashlytics - Aggregate data from different projects

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

It's not duplicate from [Fabric Crashlytics - Aggregate data from different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032726/fabric-crashlytics-aggregate-data-from-different-projects) because the answer may be outdated (uses Fabric).

I have a single code base that in CI/CD process turn into multiple apps into the store.

How can I consolidate the data between these apps in Firebase?
(BigQuery answers would be appreciated too)

Even if it is multiple apps with different users, my Support Team has to have a consolidated vision of them to track or identify issues.

Comment: In Firebase there isn't a way to aggregate the Crashlytics data into a single source. Exporting the info into BigQuery and then querying those tables to aggregate the data can be a workaround.